# JS - Inserting, Deleting and Adding data in JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on this JavaScript project where all the data is stored in a local JSON file, I have been able to read the information on this file, but I have seem to be lost on how to add and modify information on this JSON file, can someone please point me in to the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: First, welcome to Stack Overflow. Second, can you please post some code so we have any idea what we're looking at?

Comment: Are you talking on the server side? Are you using nodejs?

Comment: The right direction would be to load your file into a JSON object add more data (obj.newProp = 'something'; obj.existingProp.newSubProp = 'somethingElse') to that object and serialize back to a file. Or, if you need to process the file as pure text, you need to be really careful, but I would not recommend that approach.

Comment: For this project I am only allowed to use js and its frameworks, html5, css, sass, but no server script. So I know how to read from the json file, but I dont know how to store the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is essentially doing **File/Directory I/O** (read & write) on the contents of a file composed of **json** (a string, data structure format). In particular, you want to write the contents back to file using Javascript; well, currently,..

There isn't a web standard, or endorsed specification for writing files using javascript. Modern browsers continue to implement their own APIs.

- Google's [FileSystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/) for Google Chrome, Opera. ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileSystem))

  - additional reference: [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)
  - no longer being worked on as a web standard.
  - will continue to be an API with Chrome and Apps within their App center.
  - However, there is a github-based W3C Draft dated this year that contradicts the notion that FileSystem API is dead; http://w3c.github.io/filesystem-api/Overview.html, it also seemingly includes the FileHandler API.
- Mozilla's [FileHandler API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_Handle_API) for firefox.

These APIs use aspects of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (in particular, the interface for [blob](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)). The state of **File API** is still 'Work in Progress'; the status of the document: 'Last Call Working Draft'. ***this reiterates the point that there is, currently, no standardized, endorsed javascript implementation for file/directory I/O***

Since these are not web standardized, they are not recommended for production; and are not endorsed, recommended by W3C.

---

Noteworthy: 
The [FileWriter](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html) interface inherits from the [FileSaver](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html) interface, but was only implemented in Chrome's webkit (which Opera inherits now). (Note: it was stated that there is no constructor for the class implementing FileWriter).

Other and past solutions were to use Flash components as a workaround to implement 'Save As' functionality. In Turn, there are polyfills and shims for implementing these experimental or unstandardized specs to unsupported devices/user-agents.

---

It is still indeterminable to me whether your project here is for internal purposes. If you're building an intranet application or attempting to do a utility script that isn't intended to be standardized and/or publicly accessible in production, then I recommend you review and use these APIs.

Answer (score 1):

With the `Jquery` ,you can try something like below,to fetch the data and then later on you can manipulate it as Java Script object.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function loadJson() {
                $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $.getJSON('file.json', function(json) {
                            console.log(json);
                        });
                    });
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadJson();">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: considering OP tagged `jquery`.. you're answer may be the most relevant to his circumstances.. although, there may be a better approach..

Comment: @BrettCaswell ,yes there are couple of ways to solve to this problem,but i tried to provide closer as per the OP tags.

Comment: I know how to access and read the JSON file, what I dont know is how to store the changes.

Comment: @BrettCaswell - I know how to access and read the JSON file, what I dont know is how to store the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parseJSON jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) to convert string to JSON object and then modify it.
Then you can use [JSON.stringify JavaScript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert edited JSON object to string.